# How to change an Apify actor parameter via API

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, apify

I want to call an Apify actor and specify a parameter value via a call to the Apify API.

The actor is the [Google Search Results Scraper located here](https://apify.com/apify/google-search-scraper).

[Here is where the docs say](https://apify.com/apify/google-search-scraper?section=input-schema) to use `queries` as the object property name in the API call payload.

> The following table shows specification of the actor INPUT fields as defined by its input schema. These fields can be [...] provided in a JSON object when running the actor using the API. Read more in docs.

...

> Search queries or URLs
>
> Google Search queries (e.g. food in NYC) and/or full URLs (e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=food+NYC).
>
> Enter one item per line.
>
> Optional
>   Type: String
>
> JSON example
>
> ```
> "queries": "Hotels in NYC
>   Restaurants in NYC
>   https://www.google.com/search?q=restaurants+in+NYC"
> ```

After I run my Google Apps Script code, I expect to see a change in the `searchQueries.term` parameter to be the following.

Apify — what I expect to see

```
"searchQuery": {
  "term": "Banks in Phoenix", // what I am trying to change to by API call
  // [...]
},
```

But what I actually get is the same parameter value as existed the last time I ran the actor manually. As follows.

Apify — what I actually see

```
"searchQuery": {
  "term": "CPA firms in Newark", // remaining from last time I ran the actor manually
  // [...]
},
```

Here is the code I'm running from Google Apps Script.

Code.gs

```
const runSearch = () => {
  const apiEndpoint= `https://api.apify.com/v2/actor-tasks/<MY-TASK-NAME>/run-sync?token=<MY-TOKEN>`
  const formData = {
    method: 'post',
    queries: 'Banks in Phoenix',
  };
  const options = {
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiEndpoint, options,);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The queries look good. I just don't know the details of UrlFetchApp. Normally, you would want to send body: JSON.stringify(formData) and also method: 'POST'

Comment: You are not getting any error message no? Also, could you try follow @LukášKřivka suggestion of using in the body ```JSON.stringify(formData)``` and let me know if that works? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `payload` property in the `request` object.

Change:

```
queries: 'Banks in Phoenix',
```

to:

```
payload: {
  queries: 'Banks in Phoenix',
}
```

Code.gs

```
const runSearch = () => {
  const apiEndpoint= `https://api.apify.com/v2/actor-tasks/<MY-TASK-NAME>/run-sync?token=<MY-TOKEN>`
  const formData = {
    method: 'post',
    payload: {
      queries: 'Banks in Phoenix',
    },
  };
  const options = {
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiEndpoint, options,);
}
```